# Creating a SPA using Angular JS and ng-show?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

I've recently completed CodeSchool's tutorial on Angular JS.

I want to create a simple SPA which changes a certain block of content inside a constant frame upon an anchor click.

I was thinking that I could cuse `ng-click` on the anchor tags, change a variable inside a controller, and based on the value of the variable, display a different custom directive using `ng-show`.

I'm a little bit hesitant to use `ng-show` because I'm not sure if that simply hides the element or if it is using AJAX to pull the new content, and dump the old directive.

This question is a bit difficult to put into words.

If I'm using `ng-show` to display the different custom directives am I loading the content of all the custom directives and simply showing or not showing them, or am I just loading the directive in which `ng-show` is `true`?

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: It's kind of hard to phrase. Let me change my question and try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-show` simply manages the display state. All elements are created and are present on the page, only some of them may not be visible yet.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking (I think) is:

1. Are all the elements that I will `ng-show` already present on the page?
2. Will this slow down the page?
3. Are there security risks with this?

Yes, all the elements are present already. `ng-show` just changes the `display` attribute.

If you have lots of stuff on your SPA, then the more elements you have and that you are showing or hiding will force a lot of DOM repaints, especially because of AngularJS's dirty checking.

Yes, there are potential security risks in some instances (only if you are hiding or showing stuff based on authentication, which should be done server-side).

> I'm not sure if that simply hides the element or if it is using AJAX
>   to pull the new content, and dump the old directive.

No, `ng-show` does not handle AJAX requests. So it won't "dump" any previously bound directive.

> am I just loading the directive in which ng-show is true?

No. The directive will be bound to the correct element. I wouldn't be concerned with these issues. Because remember, any time something changes in AngularJS (a DOM manipulation, other asynchronous event, data change, etc.), everything updates itself (this is the "dirty checking" everyone talks about, and is another reason why gigantic AngularJS SPAs can feel slow.)

## Is this the best way to do it?

Probably not. The idiomatic way is to use an `ng-view` which dynamically loads an HTML view based on whatever the route is (look up `ng-route`, which is AngularJS's go-to front-end routing module). If you separate concerns appropriately, then you won't have trouble with "dumping directives" as you say.